# SSRS Data Driven Subscription Not Generating File

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, subscription

In SQL Server 2014 I have a data driven subscription that is executing successfully, but no file is generated. It is a Windows File Share subscription and the report has three parameters. I've tried removing all the parameters to see if it was an issue with that, but it still does not work. I've also verified the file path and the query the subscription is based is correct so don't think there is an issue there.

The subscription returns the message:

> Processing: 0 processed of 281 total; 0 errors.

**EDIT #1:**

More information:

- I'm trying to save the files to a shared drive on test computer.
- I've given "full control" rights to the service for SQL Server Agent and
  SSRS to the folder.
- I'm logged in as a user on a domain.

Images of steps followed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT #2:**

I'm getting the following errors from the log file located at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MYINSTANCE\Reporting Services\LogFiles"

1) Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: AuthzInitializeContextFromSid: Win32 error: 1355, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;

2) Error occurred processing subscription XX: Failure writing file filename : The report server has encountered a configuration error.

3) Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSException: The report server has encountered a configuration error.  ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error.

Comment: it says 0 processed.. which means the subscription is not complete and is still running. Does the account that is running the subscription have access to the share to write to it?

Comment: I added "Everyone" to the root of share folder that it is trying to access. For example the path is "C:\Test\MyCo\Exports". I added the "Everyone" account to the "Test" folder (which is a share).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the **`Subscriptions`**  table in the **ReportServer**  database for more detail about the subscriptions. For more detail, you can refer to the [How to monitor report subscriptions](https://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/ssrs-how-to-monitor-report-subscriptions/).

You can check the UserName column values  the user have permissions and other details.

```
 SELECT *
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions AS s
     JOIN
     ReportServer.dbo.Users AS us
     ON us.UserID = s.OwnerId;
```

At the same time you can check the **`ExecutionLog3`** table **`RowCount`** column in order to figure out the subscribed report returned any rows.Therefore, you can find out more details about the issue of the report.

**EDITED**

I simulated your error in my SSRS and then handled the problem with the help of the following steps.

- Checked the error log files of the SSRS and find out the find out the

> "An impersonation error occurred using the security context of the
>   current user"

error.

- At first I refered to [Configuration Manager Report Subscription to File Share fails with “An impersonation error occurred using the security context of the current user.”](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/matt_hinsons_manageability_blog/2017/02/17/configuration-manager-report-subscription-to-file-share-fails-with-an-impersonation-error-occurred-using-the-security-context-of-the-current-user/) link but it didn't help to me.

  - Create a new data-driven subscription
  - Change the path share **\ComputerName\Share** to **\ComputerName\c$\Share**
  - In the data-driven subscription settings, I set the admin account to **User name** and **Password** fields.

Comment: As above, nothing out of the ordinary stood out. But, the RowCount is zero. However, if you run the report as well as the query used in the subscription, rows are returned.

Comment: You can  check the edited answer , I hope , it may help to you

Comment: If I understood you, in step 4 of my screenshots I used "\\desktop-blah\c$\Test\MyCo\Exports" for the Path field and my "Domain\User" for the User name field. And the "Domain\User" has admin rights. If true, this didn't work.

Comment: Indicates that the delivery to the file share location did not succeed; this message is from the file share delivery extension  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/monitor-reporting-services-subscriptions?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsql%2Freporting-services%2Fsubscriptions%2Fmonitor-reporting-services-subscriptions%3Fview%3Dsql-server-ver15 In my thought your problem main reason can be UNC path format and share issue or user permison problem.